# Passing previously defined variables into Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function, onfocus

I am having problems passing arguments into a Javascript function using the onFocus HTML event. I want a way to pass a previously defined variable into the function. My Javascript code currently looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var field1 = "Field 1 is selected";
    var field2 = "Field 2 is selected";

    function fieldSelect(field) {
        var message = field;
        document.getElementById("explain").innerHTML = message.toString();
    }

</script>
```

With the HTML looking like:

```
...
<input type="text" id="field1" onFocus="fieldSelect(field1)">
<input type="text" id="field2" onFocus="fieldSelect(field2)">
...
<p id="explain"></p>
```

So when you click on one field the string variable is passed into the function and the paragraph tags display which field is selected under the form.

Comment: It should work, what is wrong? Can you see any error in console?

Comment: I'm running it in the browser and after tinkering with it I managed to get it to output "[object HTMLInputElement]" but not the string.

Comment: Your code works fine. Check this demo. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w7qch3av/) I think you're missing something.

Comment: I agree should work, here is a fiddle with it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though Darshan provided you a workaround, your problem is something else.

Your HTML structure in this [page](http://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/MorganJE11/test.html) is like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var field1 = "Field 1 is selected";
    var field2 = "Field 2 is selected";

    function fieldSelect(field) {
        var message = field;
        document.getElementById("explain").innerHTML = message.toString();
    }
    </script>
<head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="field1" onFocus="fieldSelect(field1)">
        <input type="text" id="field2" onFocus="fieldSelect(field2)">
    </form>
    <p id="explain"></p>
</body>
```

Now, your script tag is placed in the `head` and you create two variables with the names `field1` and `field2`.

Later, in the `body`, you create two input elements with the ids `field1` and `field2`. Browsers automatically create variables with the ids and these variables refer to the element with that id. In the `head`, you set `field1` to `"Field 1 is selected"` but once you created the input element with the id `field1` in the `body`, the value of `field1` gets overwritten and `field1` refers to the input element.

And that's why, in your `fieldSelect` function, you try to print the string `"Field 1 is selected"` but you end up printing the input element `[object HTMLInputElement]`

What you can do is move your script tag inside and at the end of the body element, or if script tag must stay in the head, you should give your input elements or your variables different names.

Comment: That's fixed it in a much cleaner way. I didn't realise that html ids are stored using variable names. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

use bind() to make a function with pre-specified initial arguments.

```
    var field1 = "Field 1 is selected";
    var field2 = "Field 2 is selected";

    function fieldSelect(field) {
        var message = field;
        document.getElementById("explain").innerHTML = message.toString();
    }

 var callback1 = fieldSelect.bind(undefined, field1);
 var callback2 = fieldSelect.bind(undefined, field2);


<input type="text" id="field1" onFocus="callback1()">
<input type="text" id="field2" onFocus="callback2()">
```

Comment: Fixed! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when the event is triggered, variable with the same name as element's id is created with reference to that element. It hides the global variable with the same name which was defined before. You can still access global variables from window scope like this:

```
<input type="text" id="field1" onFocus="fieldSelect(window.field1)">
<input type="text" id="field2" onFocus="fieldSelect(window.field2)">
```